# BASH counting numbers on all lines

Tags: bash, shell, awk, lines, counting

I need help with my bash script.

The task is counting total size of files in directory. I already did it ( using ls, awk and grep). My output may look like this for example:

```
1326
40
598
258
12
$
```

These numbers means size of files in directory.
I need to count them all and I stuck here.
So I would be really grateful if someone could tell me how to count them all (and find the total size of files in directory)

Thank you

Comment: Just a gotcha that I have fallen into, be careful of hard-links where two (for example) names refer to just one file.  Not sure where you are getting these sizes from, but if `ls -l` check the 2nd column (the number of hard-links).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk '$1+0==$1{sum+=$1; count++} END{print sum, count}'
```

adds up and counts all the numbers ($1+0==$1 for a number, but not for a string) and print them the sum and count when done.

Answer (score 2):

well, in Unix shell programing, never forget the most basic philosophy, being:

> [*Keep It Simple, Stupid!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Eric_Raymond.E2.80.99s_17_Unix_Rules)

which is the French for *Use the right tool that does one thing, but does it well*. You can achieve to do what you want with a mix of `ls` or `find`, and `grep`, and `awk`, and `cut`, and `sed` and …, or you can use the tool that has been designed for calculating files sizes.

And that tool is [`du`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du):

```
% du -chs /directory
4.3G    /directory
4.3G    total
```

Though, it will give the *total* size of every file within every directory of the given path. If you want to limit it to just the files within the directory (and not the ones below), you can do:

```
% du -chsS /directory
3G      /directory
3G      total
```

For more details, refer to the manual page [`man du`], and here are the arguments I'm using in the answer:

```
-c, --total             produce a grand total 
-h, --human-readable    print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G) 
-s, --summarize         display only a total for each argument
```

if you remove `-s` you'll have the size details for each file of the directory, if you remove `-h` you'll have full size in bytes (instead of rounding into a more readable form), if you remove `-c` you won't have the grand total (i.e. the `total` line at the end).

HTH